# azure devops server : revoke access from Domain Admin User

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-server-2019

I'am recently installed Azure DevOps Server 2019 in on-premises server.

However, i'am so confused : How i can block access from Domain Admin User Group : all memebers can access and manage all project and collection

I ask for idea to implement that

Thank you

EDIT :

I also try to delete the user admin group via TFS Console , but not work

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's work

I remove the `AD domain admin` group from the local group `administrator` , with this way ; only the specific user in the local group `administrator` , can access to all project

Answer (score 2):

> azure devops server : revoke access from Domain Admin User

You could try to remove the Domain Admin User Group from its parent group, like `Project Collection Administrators`.

- Check which group the domain admins group is a member of
- In Team Foundation Server Administration Console tool, navigate to Group Membership page. Find out the Domain Admin User Group is under which groups, and remove:

  [image]
- Or you can move the member in that group:

  [image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Some group cannot be deleted

Comment: @KivenWanda, Try to find the  parent groups, then move this group from the member not work for you?

Comment: @KivenWanda, um, can not remove it? Or any other, would you please share some more info about this issue and what have you tried? If possible, please check this thread:https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/868198/tfs-can-you-delete-the-domain-admins-under-the-win.html

Comment: I've add a image to more explain , in my question